# Legend position control within rotated polar axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, rotating, legend

How can I shift (control) the position of the legend within rotated polar axis environment? (e.g. shift into the south-east corner?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{lgray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{dgray}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=90 + \pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=00,
  xmax=90,
  %xtick={0,30,60,90}
  xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
  xtick={0,15,...,90},
  ]  
\addplot[red,no markers,smooth] table{
   0 1
   30 2
   60 3
   90 2
    };    
\addlegendentry{Text1}
\addplot[no markers,smooth] table{
   0 2
   30 3
   60 1
   90 1
    };
\addlegendentry{Text2}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't ask me to explain *why* this works, but a short experiment shows that you can get the legend where you want, if you add `legend style={at={(1,2.1)}}` directly after your `xtick=` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just shift it form its default position use `xshift` and/or `yshift` inside `legend style` key in this way:

[image]

(you can also use axis coordinate in this way `legend style={anchor=north west, at={(axis cs:45,4)}}`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{lgray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{dgray}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=90 + \pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=00,
  xmax=90,
  %xtick={0,30,60,90}
  xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
  xtick={0,15,...,90},
legend style={xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-.2cm}
%legend style={anchor=north west, at={(axis cs:45,4)}}
  ]  
\addplot[red,no markers,smooth] table{
   0 1
   30 2
   60 3
   90 2
    };    
\addlegendentry{Text1}
\addplot[no markers,smooth] table{
   0 2
   30 3
   60 1
   90 1
    };
\addlegendentry{Text2}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nicely working, prefer the commented out line ...at={(axis cs:45,4)}

Answer (score 4):

You can position the legend relative to the axis using (without hard coding any lengths):

```
legend style={at=(current axis.south east), anchor=south west}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{lgray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{dgray}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=90 + \pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=00,
  xmax=90,
  %xtick={0,30,60,90}
  xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
  xtick={0,15,...,90},
  legend style={at=(current axis.south east), anchor=south west}
  ]  
\addplot[red,no markers,smooth] table{
   0 1
   30 2
   60 3
   90 2
    };    
\addlegendentry{Text1}
\addplot[no markers,smooth] table{
   0 2
   30 3
   60 1
   90 1
    };
\addlegendentry{Text2}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is nicely working, although better control by the following